# mongosniff is missing in mongo package

Tags: mongodb, installation

I installed `mongodb-10gen` version 2.4.6 in Debian. This package does not include `mongosniff`.

How can I install a *pre-built* version of `mongosniff` in Debian ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is to do with a libpcap dependency that mongosniff has, to explain why this is the case, take a look [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1738?focusedCommentId=155987&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-155987) and [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/distributions/2009-January/000288.html) for the history.

At the moment, that means that you need to go to the [MongoDB downloads](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) page and get the `mongosniff` binary from one of the tarballs provided there.  For 64-bit Linux, version 2.4.6 specifically, you would want [this version](http://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-2.4.6.tgz), though there is no specific reason not to use a later version of the `mongosniff` tool with 2.4.6

I would also note that [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) has MongoDB dissectors built in, so you can also use that to read/view a standard `tcpdump` of MongoDB traffic as an alternative.  For an example, take a look at my Q&A over on Serverfault related to filtering:

https://serverfault.com/a/521966/108132